# Prove $C(n) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}((\frac{1 + \sqrt{5}}{2})^{n + 2} - (\frac{1 - \sqrt{5}}{2})^{n + 2})$

Tags: combinatorics

Given:

$1 + \frac{1 + \sqrt{5}}{2} = (\frac{1 + \sqrt{5}}{2})^{2}$

$1 + \frac{1 - \sqrt{5}}{2} = (\frac{1 - \sqrt{5}}{2})^{2}$

If C(n) is the number of 0/1 strings of length n that do not contain
consecutive 1s, prove $C(n) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}((\frac{1 + \sqrt{5}}{2})^{n + 2} - (\frac{1 - \sqrt{5}}{2})^{n + 2})$.

The proof is probably by induction, but I'm confused as to what the base case might be for this particular problem. And once I assume $n = k$, what might the first steps be in proving $n = k + 1$?

Thank you. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: This is also known as Binet's formula and gives a closed form expression of the [Fibonacci sequence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number). So you just have to show that your $C(n)$ follow the same recurrence as the Fibonacci sequence.

Comment: Two sign mistakes in the second "given" identity.

Answer (score 2):

This might help you.  To get a string of length $n$ that ends in $0$, simply take a string of length $n-1$ and append a $0$.  To get a string that ends in $1$, take a string of length $n-2$ and append $01$.  Therefore, you should have a recurrence relation

$$C(n)=C(n-2)+C(n-1)$$

And as TooOldForMath mentioned in his comments, you'll notice that there is $1$ string of length $0$ (the empty string) and $2$ strings of length $1$.  Two consecutive Fibonacci numbers plus the Fibonacci recurrence means your C(n) are all Fibonacci numbers.